# How to launch a setup.exe file using process.start

Tags: c#

I've a free trial launcher for the Final Fantasy XIV game. Now I want to launch it through process.start in a windows service in C#. the process starts successfully, as I can see it in the windows task manager, but it does not launch the setup file. Here is the code I've tried.

```
try {
   var process = new Process();
   var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
     WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
     FileName = "cmd.exe",
     Arguments = "/C " + setupFile + " /DIR=" + installLocation,
   };

   process.StartInfo = startInfo;
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Logger.Log.Error("Error Installing game.", ex);
}
```

Where setupfile is the complete path for ffxivsetup_ft.exe.

Comment: i think much better to do it in console application

Comment: Starting interactive processes from a service doesn’t sound like something one would want to do and there are systems in place to stop this from working. Also there’s no need to run cmd.exe to run the application.

Comment: I have to do it this way.. and the above code works for another game. I think the issue is with the startinfo.arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Care to explain why this would fix the problem and what the problem is?